# Growl notifications from delayed job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, gritter

I've just broken my existing way of getting growl-style notifications from a delayed_job, and opening up someone else's gem and hacking around isn't getting me anywhere. So I wondered: what's a sensible way to get notifications from a background task. Currently I'm using [gritter_notices](https://github.com/dapi/gritter_notices) with a ruby class like this (but I've done something to stop it working... and the documentation's not in my native tongue...)

```
#User.rb

has_gritter_notices



class DoThing

  def run_thing(books, template, client, user)
     # some code


     User.find(user).notice "<a href='/archives' target='_blank'>View Archive</a>", :level => :notice, :sticky => true, :title => "Things generated." 

  end

handle_asynchronously :run_thing

end
```

ps The error I'm getting is `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Text can't be blank`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, ignore me. I'd turned on whitelist_attributes:

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true
```

and the gem doesn't have its attributes whitelisted with `attr_accessible`.